# Black Box hidding content when debugging in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: user-interface, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a little black box that show whenever I debug my app.  It is blocking content and I cant figure out how to shut it off.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  (Picture Below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK figured it out.. There is the following code in the App.xaml.
`if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                //this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }`

You need to comment this line of code out and the frame rate counter will not appear.